# I cannot seem to create a DFA for this language

Tags: dfa, automaton

```
{w∈{a,b}∗|w has baba as a substring}
```

I am confused with this. How can I capture the following input for example?

```
aaababa
abbbaba
ababbba
ababaaaa
```

It seems there must always be baba in either middle or start or end. I must decide whether to put it always in start or middile or end?

Thanks

Comment: See Ravindrababu's video or Sanchit Jain from YouTube. It's pretty obvious question.

Answer (score 3):

By the Myhill-Nerode theorem, the states are:

- Already matched 'baba' (accepting state)
- Immediately after 'bab', and haven't matched 'baba'
- Immediately after 'ba', and haven't matched 'baba'
- Immediately after 'b', and none of the above
- None of the above (start state)

It's essentially the same DFA created by the Knuth-Morris-Pratt search algorithm.